# Chrome Extension Background Page Cookie Issue

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome Extension that loads data via jQuery from a background page, and relies on the user being logged in to the website to authenticate.

```
$.get('https://mydomain.com/myurl', function (data) {
   // do something
});
```

Ie, a user logs on normally to https://mydomain.com, and some cookies are set by the server.

In the background page, get some data for that user at /myurl  `/myurl` expects the authentication cookies to be present.

This works on a background page, but only if the the background script is reloaded after the user logs in.  Additionally, once the user logs out and the cookie is deleted from the web page, the cookie is still there in the background page!

I'd expect that the cookies on the background page to stay in sync with the cookies on the website.

Not sure if this is a feature or a bug, or I am totally doing this wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was caused by using SignalR (websockets) in my background page.  The websocket was opened before the cookie was set.  So, I had to detect a change in the cookie, close the websocket, and then reopen it so that it would get the new cookie value.